# Java - Converting a text area to a string

Tags: java, string, file

I am having a little trouble here, I want to convert a text area into a string, so i can store it in a new string and pass it to a txt file. Here is my code:

```
// ta is my textArea, things is a String

things = ta.toString();
outputFile.println(things);
closeFile();
```

But when i do this it is literally taking everything about the textArea and putting it into a string. I just want to put the text into a string, not all the values of the textArea. Any suggestions?

Comment: JTextArea.getText() maybe?  Read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

Comment: Haha so simple, but worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use something like this:

```
things = ta.getText();
outputFile.println(things);
closeFile();
```

Comment: Actually, he needs to learn to read the documentation before firing off basic questions.  IMHO ...